# Flip random elements on a page in JS using CSS classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some squares on a page that when clicked flip over, like a card so you can see the back.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d1botfu2/

That seems to work fine, however, I would also like every few seconds a square to flip over automatically (almost like a screen saver) then flip back and flip another random one using the same animation as the click event.

I have tried using a toggle but it turns it white

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function change() {
    randomElements = jQuery("div.flipper").get().sort(function(){
        return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5
    }).slice(0,1)
    $(randomElements).toggle('active');
    console.log("Change");
}

setInterval(function () {
    change();
}, 1000);

});
```

Comment: You get a random colour but don't do anything with it.

Comment: Sorry that was there when I was trying to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gone thru' your code and made some fixes. Hope this is the solution you are looking for,

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function change() { debugger;
    randomElements = jQuery("div.flip-container").get().sort(function(){
        return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5
    }).slice(0,1)

    $(randomElements).toggleClass('active');
    console.log("Change");
}

setInterval(function () {
    change();
}, 1000);
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/d1botfu2/4/

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this one: https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

and this one: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp

Using a random number, you can select a random element of a class type.

untested example:

```
$( ".div.flipper:eq(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + ')" ).trigger('click')
```

^This should select a random card between 1 and 10 (or more precisely, 0 and 9) and trigger its `click`-event

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    $( ".div.flipper:eq(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + ')" ).trigger('click')
    flipTimer ;
}, 1000);
```